# Reimplementing Enum.HasFlag for use in Mono 2.6

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert Jint for use in Mono 2.6. Unfortunately Mono 2.6 doesn't have Enum.HasFlag and that's something they use in Jint. I should also add that I'm quite new to C#.

According to the MSDN page ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) the implementation should be

```
thisInstance And flag = flag
```

but this doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. If these are all bitwise operations shouldn't it be more like this?

```
thisInstance & flag == flag
```

So, the line I'm trying to modify is

```
Writable = !fieldInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FieldAttributes.InitOnly);
```

I've stuck this in

```
var thisInstance = fieldInfo.Attributes;
var thisFlag = FieldAttributes.InitOnly;
var hasFlag1 = thisInstance & thisFlag == thisFlag;
var hasFlag2 = thisInstance And thisFlag = thisFlag;
Writable1 = !hasFlag1;
Writable2 = !hasFlag2;
```

and understandably the compiler doesn't like either of these. For hasFlag1 I get

```
Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Reflection.FieldAttributes' and 'bool'
```

And for hasFlag2:

```
Unexpected symbol 'And'
```

Just want to know if anyone knows how this is meant to be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems based on the error of the compiler that == takes precedence over &.
Therefore your line is evaluated like this:
    var hasFlag1 = thisInstance & (thisFlag == thisFlag);

What you want is this:

```
var hasFlag1 = (thisInstance & thisFlag) == thisFlag;
```

So if you add the parentheses, the compiler error should go away.

Most probably `And` is the VB equivalent of `&`

Comment: Bam, nailed it. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Ah yeah I hadn't realised that that line was not specific to C#. You're probably right about the And operator.